# Any social database / forms framework?

Tags: database, content-management-system, social-networking, wiki

I want to knock up a quick social **data-driven** website without having to spend too much time on it.

However, all the standard CMS that I've looked at (Wordpress, Drupal, Elgg, Dolphin etc.) seem to revolve around a *fixed data structure and the site admin creating the content* (e.g. blogs, news, static pages, contact forms, polls), rather than letting the *site admin design a custom data structure with associated CRUD forms, and letting the users create the structured content*.

So the question is, **does a framework for this kind of site already exist**?

Here is an example of what I have in mind in more detail:

Basically I want to define a data schema, and create a bunch of forms for users to enter data that follows the schema (with appropriate validation etc.). They can then:

- view the data
- edit the data (ideally keeping a version history/diff)
- authorise certain other users to edit it (e.g. their family/colleagues)
- allow all registered users to view and comment on the data

So a simple example might be a 'my mp3 collection' site (this is an example only). The data would be something like

```
//Editable list of artists
table artist {
    id (id),
    name (string),
    homepage (url),
    wikipediaPage (url)
}

//Editable list of albums
table album {
    artistId (id), //link to artist
    id (id), //album id
    name (string),
    year (int)
}

//user collections
table useralbum {
    userId (id),
    artistId (id),
    albumId (id),
    myRating (int),
    review (text)
}
```

The site would consist of a number of forms that let registered users create and edit these collections, share them with each other etc.

Answer (score 1):

Elgg is far from "fixed data structure and the site admin creating the content". On the contrary, it has very flexible data structure as it implements EAV, so when it comes to implementing custom "entities" (or object types), all you need is to name it and nothing stops you from immediately writing data to any fields you want without defining them first. Have a look at general overview of [data model](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Engine/DataModel)

However there's no admin interface to define forms and entity types, but api for developers. Elgg is not a classical CMS, but social networking framework to build custom solutions. Keep in mind existing [plugins base](http://community.elgg.org/plugins) that may contain solutions similar to what you want and thus easy to adapt.

If you want to avoid programming at all costs and there's no plugins already implementing particular feature - that's probably not framework for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll take another look at Elgg in more detail.